# Are Django's QuerySets lazy enough to cope with large data sets?

Tags: django, django-models, lazy-loading

I think I've read somewhere that Django's ORM lazily loads objects. Let's say I want to update a large set of objects (say 500,000) in a batch-update operation. Would it be possible to simply iterate over a very large QuerySet, loading, updating and saving objects as I go?

Similarly if I wanted to allow a paginated view of all of these thousands of objects, could I use the built in [pagination facility](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) or would I manually have to run a window over the data-set with a query each time because of the size of the QuerySet of all objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the batch update is possible using a SQL query, then i think using sql-queries or django-orm will not make a major difference. But if the update actually requires loading each object, processing the data and then updating them, you can use the orm or write your own sql query and run update queries on each of the processed data, the overheads completely depends on the code logic.

The built-in pagination facility runs a limit,offset query (if you are doing it correct), so i don't think there are major overheads in the pagination either ..

Answer (score 3):

If you evaluate a 500000-result queryset, which is big, it will get cached in memory. Instead, you can use the [`iterator()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) method on your queryset, which will return results as requested, without the huge memory consumption.

Also, use `update()` and `F()` objects in order to do simple batch-updates in single query.

Answer (score -2):

As I benchmarked this for my current project with dataset of 2.5M records in one table.

I was reading information and counting records, for example, I needed to find IDs of records, which field "name" was updated more than once in certain timeframe. Django benchmark was using ORM, to retrieve all records and then to iterate through them. Data was saved in list for future processing. No any debug output, except result print in the end.

On the other end, I was using MySQLdb which was executing same queries (got from Django) and building same structure, using classes for storing data and saving instances in list for future processing. No any debug output, except result print in the end.

I found that:

```
                      without Django  with Django
 execution time             x             10x
 memory consumption         y             25y
```

And I was only reading and counting, without performing update/insert queries.

Try to investigate this question for yourself, benchmark isn't hard to write and execute.

Comment: Sorry 10 times and 25 times more than what? Straight SQL queries?

Comment: Full read of data and performing some activities with them took 10 times more time and 25 times more memory, when I was using Django ORM than when I was using SQL queries and manipulating with retrieved data as python list.

Comment: -1. This is a meaningless statistic. Plus, it depends on how you were using the ORM - `len(queryset)` for example can be massively less efficient than `queryset.count()`.